# Flipping a view in titanium like a card

Tags: ios, titanium

I am using Titanium and running the emulator on iOS7. I am trying to get a card like flipping animation. I have it half way working. It will current flip from `front` to `back`, but as soon as I click it again, the app crashes and my console isn't showing anything.

The docs say:

`The new view being transitioned to should NOT be a child of another view or of the animating view.`

Maybe I am understanding that wrong because I cannot seem to make this work. My code so far is:

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var noThumbColors   = ['#555555','#cccccc'];
var noThumbColors2  = ['#ff0000','#000'];

var views   = [];
var fronts  = [];
var backs   = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++)
{   
    fronts[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        id:i,
        name:"front",
        width:150,
        height:150,
        backgroundGradient:{
            type: 'linear',
            startPoint: { x: '0%', y: '0%' },
            endPoint: { x: '0%', y: '100%' },
            colors: [ { color: noThumbColors[0], offset: 0.0}, { color: noThumbColors[1], offset: 1.0 } ],
        },
        currentAngle: 10
    });

    backs[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        id:i,
        name:"back",
        width:150,
        height:150,
        backgroundGradient:{
            type: 'linear',
            startPoint: { x: '0%', y: '0%' },
            endPoint: { x: '0%', y: '100%' },
            colors: [ { color: noThumbColors2[1], offset: 0.0}, { color: noThumbColors2[0], offset: 1.0 } ],
        },
        currentAngle: 10
    });
    win.add(backs[i]);
    win.add(fronts[i]);
    fronts[i].addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        log(e.source.name);
        t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT;
        e.source.animate({view:backs[e.source.id],transition:t});

    });

    backs[i].addEventListener('click', function(e)
    {
        log(e.source.name);
        t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT;
        e.source.animate({view:fronts[e.source.id],transition:t});
    });
}

function log(msg)
{
    Ti.API.info(msg);
}
```

### **The finished working code (will produce 3 squares that will flip back and forth independently):**

```
var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow;
var noThumbColors   = ['#555555','#cccccc'];
var noThumbColors2  = ['#ff0000','#000'];
var containers  = [];
var fronts      = [];
var backs       = [];

for (var i = 0; i < 3; i++)
{   
    containers[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        top:50 + (i * 155),
        width:150,
        height:150
    });

    fronts[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        id:i,
        name:"front",
        width:150,
        height:150,
        backgroundGradient:{
            type: 'linear',
            startPoint: { x: '0%', y: '0%' },
            endPoint: { x: '0%', y: '100%' },
            colors: [ { color: noThumbColors[0], offset: 0.0}, { color: noThumbColors[1], offset: 1.0 } ],
        },
        currentAngle: 10
    });

    backs[i] = Ti.UI.createView({
        id:i,
        name:"back",
        width:150,
        height:150,
        backgroundGradient:{
            type: 'linear',
            startPoint: { x: '0%', y: '0%' },
            endPoint: { x: '0%', y: '100%' },
            colors: [ { color: noThumbColors2[1], offset: 0.0}, { color: noThumbColors2[0], offset: 1.0 } ],
        },
        currentAngle: 10
    });
    containers[i].add(backs[i]);
    containers[i].add(fronts[i]);
    win.add(containers[i]);
}

win.addEventListener('click', function(e)
{
    if (e.source.name === "front")
    {
        containers[e.source.id].animate({view:backs[e.source.id],transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT});
    }
    else if (e.source.name === "back")
    {
        containers[e.source.id].animate({view:fronts[e.source.id],transition:Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT});
    }
});

function log(msg)
{
    Ti.API.info(msg);
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on [KitchenSink example app](https://github.com/appcelerator/KitchenSink/blob/master/Resources/ui/handheld/ios/baseui/transitions.js) you should call animate on parent object of views which you want to animate. I also made small refactoring and created just one eventListener attached to window instead of many functions for every single object you create. It's good to use [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/), which will tell you that creating function in for loop isn't the best practise.

```
for (var i = 0; i < 1; i++) { 
    /* your code */
    win.add(backs[i]);
    win.add(fronts[i]);
   /* both addEventListener() are removed from here */
}

win.addEventListener('click', function(e) {
    var t;
    if (e.source.name === 'front') {
        t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_LEFT;
        win.animate({view:backs[e.source.id],transition:t});
    } else {
        t = Ti.UI.iPhone.AnimationStyle.FLIP_FROM_RIGHT;
        win.animate({view:fronts[e.source.id],transition:t});
    }
});
```

Comment: I was just about to post that I figured it out. You are correct in that you add the event listener on the parent.

Comment: I added my solution to my original question. I moved the event listener out of the for loop and managed to get it working with `win`

Comment: Yes, my first try was also by adding additional wrapping view but then I tried to use it with window to check if that additional object is really necessary.

Answer (score 1):

Here is the simple way to flip a window like card

You have to set the property of window as follows:

```
 var win = Ti.UI.currentWindow({
   height:'auto',
   width:'auto,'
   modal:true    
   });

 win.open({
    modalTransitionStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_TRANSITION_STYLE_FLIP_HORIZONTAL,
    modalStyle: Ti.UI.iPhone.MODAL_PRESENTATION_FORMSHEET
 });
```

Hope it will help.

Comment: I am flipping a view though, not a window.

Comment: There is no method named currentWindow(), this is the object which returns the reference of current visible window if created by passing the the url parameter in createWindow function